# Zip deploy azure function from storage account

Tags: python, deployment, azure-functions, zip

I'm trying to zip deploy an azure function from a blob storage.

I have set `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT,` to true.
I have also set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to the remote url.

I am able to deploy easily if the function is in a remote url. However, I can't seem to do it if I have it as a blob on azure.

The prefarable runtime for this is python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having the zip deploy from storage account you need to navigate to your .zip blob in your storage account and get the generated SAS token for that blob.

[image]

Then add the same url in your Function App Application settings for `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`.

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:-** This option is the only one supported for running from a package on Linux hosted in a Consumption plan.

For more information on this you can refer [Run your functions from a package file in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#using-website_run_from_package--url)

Comment: Thank you @swethaKandikonda-mt. I have another question, how do I download a python function as a zip? The download button seems to be greyed out, for python functions.

Comment: @jay4592, you can only download the code as a zip if the functions are directly created from the Azure portal. You cannot download when you have deployed your functions.