# Azure Functions: How to run Linux Consumption Zip Deploy?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am running Linux on WSL and want to publish the hello-world example to an Azure Function using the Linux consumption plan on Python 3.10.

This is not a solution for me: [Zip deploy azure function from storage account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71070103/zip-deploy-azure-function-from-storage-account)

My hello world example is:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello")
def test_function(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

My local.settings.json is:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT": true,
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "redacted",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "redacted",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "redacted",
    
  }
}
```

requirements.txt:

```
azure-functions
```

I am deploying by zipping my folder and then using the az cli:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g rg_here -n fun_name_here --src my_zip_file.zip
```

In fact the above nor from the terminal will work, either.

```
func azure functionapp publish my_fun_name
```

By not work, I mean that I get either this response:

```
No HTTP triggers found.
```

or

```
Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.
```

And my functions are not visible on the portal or VS Code.

Comment: I encountered similar problem when I manually zipped the function binaries and the zipped file did not contain `.azurefunctions` hidden folder. Please check if that's the case with you as well. I was using MacOS.

Comment: If that is zip deployment, you have to enable/add the configuration setting in azure portal function app > `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` References - [74195407](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74202953/19615125) and [75877908](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75898779/19615125)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the commands from the SO [71617500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71617500/zip-deploy-of-azure-function-was-a-success-but-functions-in-azure-is-empty/71645818#71645818) and it worked for me.

As per [MS document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package), to enable your function app to run from a package, add a `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=<URL>` setting to your app settings for functions apps running on Linux in a Consumption plan.

Firstly I set the value as `"SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT": true` in **function app configuration** and `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` was automatically added during function app creation.

[image]

****init**.py**

```
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func
def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
name  =  req.params.get('name')
if  not  name:
try:
req_body  =  req.get_json()
except  ValueError:
pass
else:
name  =  req_body.get('name')
if  name:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
else:
return  func.HttpResponse(
"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
status_code=200
)
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
}
}
```

I have only zipped the following function files

[image]

Used the below command to deploy the zip file from local cli

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g iafrin-RG -n afreenfuncapp0123 --src "C:\Users\iafrin\Documents\functionApp\demo-file\hello-world-test-file.zip"
```

It got deployed successfully

[image]

I was able to see the function in the portal along with the warning and in vs code I was able to files in read-only mode as well.

[image]

[image]

```
Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.
```

Above warning says, I can't edit my files from the portal as It is running from a package and according to [MS document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#remote-build), portal editing is enabled only for HTTP and Timer triggers for Functions on Linux using Premium and Dedicated plans not for Consumption plan.

Comment: How do you have requirements.txt in the `App Files` but it is not in the folder structure? I am still unable to reproduce following this and it departs from recommended setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators&tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level

Comment: Modified my answer. Check once if you have `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` in the azure function configuration post deployment